# How to run jupyter notebook using docker with ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to docker and could not figure out how to search google to answer my question.

I am using windows OS

I've created docker image using

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install jupyter
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash demo
USER demo
WORKDIR /home/demo
ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```

and it worked fine. Now I've tried to create it again but with different libraries in requirements.txt it fails to build, it outputs `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies requirement apturl==0.5.2`. When I search what apturl is, I think we need ubuntu OS to install it.

So my question is how do you create a jupyter notebook server using docker with ubuntu libraries? (I am using Windows OS). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading pip.

```
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I am still getting the error.

Comment: RUN install apturl before running install requirements.txt. working fine for me

Comment: from my understanding, apturl is library specific to ubuntu os isn't it? if so don't I have to use ubuntu os instead of windows?

Comment: are you on windows? please specify the os on op

Comment: Yes I am using Windows OS, I specified it however it probably was hard to see, I've added it on top of question, thanks for letting me know.